# How to get the steps used to build the Neo4j Graph?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases, cypher-3.1

For example I am using the following Cypher code to build my initial graph:

```
CREATE (forrestGump:Movie {title: 'Forrest Gump', released: 1994}) 
CREATE (robert:Person:Director {name: 'Robert Zemeckis', born: 1951}) 
CREATE (tom:Person:Actor {name: 'Tom Hanks', born: 1956}) 
CREATE (tom)—[:ACTED_IN {roles: ['Forrest']}]—>(forrestGump)
```

Over time more and more Cypher code added, more CREATE and MERGE commands.

How can I get all the steps that used to build my graph?
I have tried `CALL db.schema.visualization()` but it won't provide me with the steps above.

Please guide me how can I get the building steps?

Answer (score 0):

For others that will have a similar issue, here are the docs that solved the issue:

https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.4/export/cypher/

Just choose which export procedure is suitable for your needs. It will export all the queries that used to build the graph.